# Tinymce - how to change the placeholder color?

Tags: tinymce

I am using tinymce with react.

Color used with the "placeholder" feature is dark.
I would like to change the color in order to have a consistent form

I checked the documentation and I did not found a solution for that.

How could we change the color of the placeholder ?

Answer (score 2):

The CSS that controls the placeholder text is located in the TinyMCE skin.  You can override it by supplying alternative CSS via the `content_css` or `content_style` configuration options.

The CSS you need to override is:

```
.mce-content-body[data-mce-placeholder]:not(.mce-visualblocks)::before {
  color: rgba(34,47,62,.7); 
}
```

You could do that via `content_style` directly in your configuration via simple CSS like this:

```
.mce-content-body[data-mce-placeholder]:not(.mce-visualblocks)::before {
  color: red;
}
```

Here is a working fiddle:  https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/Oyhaab

Comment: Thank you for your comment, your solution perfectly work. thanks again !

Comment: If that solved your issue can you accept the answer so people know the issue is resolved?